# ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal en este código Python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, sintaxis

Pues voy iniciando en *Python 3.8.5* y estoy leyendo un libro en el que venía tal ejercicio para la demostración de las funciones incorporadas (Built.in function) de Python, el código es:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self,name,year)
    self.name = name
    self.name = year

v1 = Vehicle("AUDI", 2018)

print(v1.name)
print(v1.year)
```

Según yo, debería imprimir: **AUDI 2018** pero por el contrario me da el siguiente error por sintaxis inválida:

> ```
> def __init__(self,name,year)
>                            ^
> ```

Comment: ¿Ta faltaron 2 puntos no?, es decir algo así: *`def __init__(self,name,year):`*

Comment: Adicional a los dos puntos que comenta el compañero @BetaM, al agregar esos dos puntos, te hará falta corregir la indentación del siguiente bloque.

Comment: Creo que por acá puedes leer un poco mas: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dos errores: Falta el ":" al final del `def` y tienes mala la indentación:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self,name,year):
        self.name = name
        self.name = year
```

Answer (score 0):

En primero lugar te faltan los dos puntos, luego que no estas configurando year, si ves tienes dos self.name, en tercer lugar la identación es importante en Python

El código te quedaría así:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name, year):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year

v1 = Vehicle("AUDI", 2018)

print(v1.name)
print(v1.year)
```